# KQL Load Balancer Bytes

Tags: azure, kql

Hi I've been trying to convert a query from bytes to GB, however I'm getting some strange results. I also get the same component showing up incrementally increasing in size, which makes sense as we are getting the bytes used, which we wold expect to see increased, but I would only like the latest set of data (when the query was run). Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated >=ago(1d)
| where Resource contains "LB"
| where MetricName contains "ByteCount"
| extend  TotalGB = Total/1024
| summarize by Resource, TimeGenerated, TotalGB, MetricName, UnitName
| sort by TotalGB desc 
| render piechart
```

In the table below, it shows the loadbal-1 reporting several times in a short window and the same for loadbal2 and 13. I'd like to capture these all in a single line, also I think I might have messed up the query for "TotalGB" (converting bytes to GB)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would only like the latest set of data (when the query was run)*

you can use the `arg_max()` aggregation function.

for example:

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1d)
| where Resource has "LoadBal"
| where MetricName == "ByteCount"
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Resource
```

---

> *I've been trying to convert a query from bytes to GB, however I'm getting some strange results... I think I might have messed up the query for "TotalGB" (converting bytes to GB)*

If the raw data is in bytes, then you need to divide it by `exp2(30)` (or `1024*1024*1024`) to get the value as GBs.

Or, you can use the `format_bytes()` function instead

for example:

```
print bytes = 18027051483.0
| extend gb_1 = format_bytes(bytes, 2),
         gb_2 = bytes/exp2(30),
         gb_3 = bytes/1024/1024/1024
```

| bytes | gb_1 | gb_2 | gb_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18027051483 | 16.79 GB | 16.7889999998733 | 16.7889999998733 |